# What are the "Rare" Monsters found throughout the Clockworks?

Tags: spiral-knights

[image]

As you can see from the picture above, on the tip panel, it reads:

> Rare Monsters
>
> Rare monsters offering unique items roam the Clockworks. Have you
>   discovered any yet?

What are these "rare" monsters it talks about? What are the unique drops? I'm not quite sure what they mean by "rare"...

Comment: Well you have well-done monsters the crispy and slightly blackend mobs, medium monsters the inbetween kind. But for those who like their monsters abit more bloody you have rare monsters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are monsters with an incredibly low spawn rate. One example is the Soul Jelly, seen **[here on the Spiral Knights wiki](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Lichen)**. While it doesn't have unique drops as far as I can tell, it's drop rate and amount is generally higher. There are other examples, like the Love Puppy, **[seen here on the wiki](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Gun_Puppy)**. It has the chance to drop even rarer items, including various Heart pendants.

If you want to browse for more kinds of rare monsters, go to the Spiral Knights wiki and search for the Monsters page. It lists all of the monster families, and if you scroll down to the bottom of a monster family page, you'll find notable examples of monsters in these families, including rare monsters and monsters removed from the game.

Rare monsters:

- Soul Jelly
- Love Puppy

  - Can drop Health Bonus Trinkets
- Rock Jelly

Comment: While I like this answer, if you could actually put the names/links of the Rare Monsters in, that would be even better!

Comment: I would love to include links to the specific monsters, but they don't really have their own page, nor do they have anchors to reference specific monsters on the family pages, so you'll have to just dig for yourself. Like I said though, look at the bottom of each page and you'll find them.